# Image retrieving using gridview

Tags: asp.net

I want to fetch data from **OLEDB SQL Server** and display it in **gridview**, I am able to fetch data except for **Image**:

```
<asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AllowPaging="True" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="False" DataSourceID="SqlDataSource1" 
        EnableModelValidation="True" Height="184px" Width="546px">
        <Columns>
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col_FirstName" HeaderText="col_FirstName" 
                SortExpression="col_FirstName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col_LastName" HeaderText="col_LastName" 
                SortExpression="col_LastName" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col_age" HeaderText="col_age" 
                SortExpression="col_age" />
            <asp:BoundField DataField="col_photo" HeaderText="col_photo" 
                SortExpression="col_photo" />
        </Columns>
    </asp:GridView>
    <asp:SqlDataSource ID="SqlDataSource1" runat="server" 
        ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString %>" 
        ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:ConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
        SelectCommand="SELECT [col_FirstName], [col_LastName], [col_age], [col_photo] FROM [tbl_PersonInfo_Test]">
    </asp:SqlDataSource>`
```

Comment: What dataType is col_photo in your SqlServer? Do you save a filePath or a blob or anything else?

Comment: @Pilgerstorfer Franz : its binary data...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you are using a **binaryField** in your dataBase you can create a simple imageHandler class. This class knows how to **load** an **Image** out of your **data storage** and **writes** it to the **responseStream**. See below for a *very rough example*.

**imageHandler.aspx**

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  if (Request.QueryString["ID"] != null)
  {
      int id = Convert.ToInt32(Request.QueryString["ID"]);

      // query your dataStorage for col_photo according to the current id
      // ...

      // access your binaryColumn
     Byte[] bytes = (Byte[])dt.Rows[0]["col_photo"]; // adapt in case you use ExecuteScalar()
     Response.Buffer = true;
     Response.Charset = "";
     Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
     Response.ContentType = "image/jpeg";
     Response.BinaryWrite(bytes);
     Response.Flush();
     Response.End();
}
```

**ASPX**

```
// don't forget to add the pkColumn to your select statement!!
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="YOUR_PK_COLUMN" 
 DataImageUrlFormatString="imageHandler.aspx?ID={0}"
 ControlStyle-Width="100" ControlStyle-Height="100"/>
```

You can find several examples on the web. See [Displaying Images in gridViews](http://www.highoncoding.com/Articles/207_Displaying_Images_from_Database_in_GridView.aspx) or [ImagesFromDBinGridView](http://aspsnippets.com/Articles/Display-images-from-SQL-Server-Database-in-ASP.Net-GridView-control.aspx) or just ask [Mr. Google](https://www.google.at/search?q=asp%3aImageField&sugexp=chrome,mod=15&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8#hl=de&sclient=psy-ab&q=show%20binary%20image%20in%20gridview%20in%20asp.net&oq=gridview%20show%20image%20b&gs_l=serp.3.2.0i19j0i8i30i19l3.104751.110618.0.114774.29.19.5.5.6.1.355.3879.0j14j4j1.19.0...0.0...1c.1.OlQLRL-9qoU&pbx=1&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_cp.r_qf.&fp=d5b3764c53169ab6&biw=1600&bih=775).

Answer (score 1):

You can try with this code - based on asp:ImageField

```
<asp:ImageField DataImageUrlField="col_photo"></asp:ImageField>
```

Link : http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx

And replace this code

```
<asp:BoundField DataField="col_photo" HeaderText="col_photo" SortExpression="col_photo" />
```

Second solution - based on `template field`

```
<asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Status" ItemStyle-HorizontalAlign="Center">
    <ItemTemplate> 
         <asp:Image ID="photo" runat="server" ImageUrl="<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "col_photo")%>"  />
    </ItemTemplate> 
</asp:TemplateField>
```

Comment: I'am happy to help you bro, i think nothing, just you must adjust your datasource (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa479350.aspx)